# GCC Linker Script Ignore PHDR / PHDRS?

Tags: gcc, ld, linker-scripts

I'm trying to target a flat file for the output of my code, where I don't want PHDR.  But it seems no matter how I set things up, in modern GCC versions, I can't avoid PHDR.

Either I get `PHDR segment not covered by LOAD segment` or if I define a PHDRS property as in my linker script as follows:

```
PHDRS
{
    header PT_NULL FILEHDR;
    text PT_NULL PHDRS;
    data PT_NULL FILEHDR;
}
```

but throw it out, I get the error `no sections assigned to phdrs`

I can't seem to find any way to force GCC to just trust me and not emit the PHDRs.  What can I put in my linker script to tell GCC that I really mean it.

*EDIT*
I found this: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=25585

If I add the following to my GCC invocation, it seems to output the binary anyway: `-Wl,--noinhibit-exec`

But, it now includes extra header data in the middle of the binary image.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution!

Either have an empty `PHDRS {...}` definition at the top (or it seems maybe you don't need it).

Then, in your sections, be sure to discard phdr and contain all the troublesome sections.

```
/* If we're on a newer compiler */
/DISCARD/: {
  *(.interp)
  *(.dynsym)
  *(.dynstr)
  *(.hash)
  *(.gnu.hash)
  *(.header)
} : phdr
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate a flat binary file, then you could just specify the output format to be “binary”.

Not sure it’s what you want

A long time a ago, when I was looking into bootloaders, I was generating the MBR using exactly that.